# Why does sexual abuse have a different mental effect than physical abuse?

Tags: emotional-abuse, physical-abuse

I was wondering why sexual abuse may be different than physical abuse in our culture?

Is it because there is a real physiological difference in the brain, or could it be from the way society taught us to address these kind of things?

Why is being raped different than being mugged by gunpoint to the victim, i.e. why would there be more severe mental trauma when sex is involved?

I tried to find objective data on this matter, but could not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it belongs on psych/neuroscience (was cogsci), it is too old to migrate. You can repost it (I edited for clarity, it would also help if you added which culture).